# Question related to fourier transform?

Tags: fourier, signal-theory

I just have a simple question

Can someone prove the fourier transform of 1. it is 2*pi*delta(omega)

but i am not able to prove it without using the properties just prove from scratch (fourier transform formula)

any link would also be useful.

Comment: I bet they can!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a proper design question.

Comment: why is it a problem using the proprieties? and what are you using?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Do you mean the "inverse fourier of 1"?

Comment: Here's a hint: What is the integral of (total area under) an infinitely-long sinewave (or cosine wave)? What if the frequency of that wave is zero -- i.e., it never crosses the X axis?

Answer (score 2):

By definition of the impulse distribution, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(\omega)\delta(\omega)d\omega = g(0)$$

The Fourier synthesis equation is

$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)e^{j\omega t}d\omega$$

These are all you need to get the result.